# SQL Server Trigger not work propertly with Entity Framework and Self Tracking Entities

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

I have a table in SQL Server with these columns:

- Name
- Description
- Volume
- LastUpdate

For this table there is a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Table1_Trigger1]
ON [dbo].[Deals]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF(UPDATE(Volume))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Table2
        SET TotalVolume = Volume * 100;
    END
END
```

The problem is that the other table records are updated even when the description column is updated (by Entity Framework) and not the volume column.

Comment: start by showing us the complete trigger code

Comment: The trigger have 600 lines of code. The problem is not in the trigger code. It looks like entity frame updates all the fields even if they have not changed and then the trigger enters the IF

Comment: leave stuff out of it and show us a reprocucable trigger. Without any code we can only guess what is going on

Comment: please edit your question and put the trigger example in there, not in a comment

Comment: your problem is that a trigger can be fired for more than one record. if update(volume) will fail if there is more than one record updated. Use the inserted table in your trigger

Comment: the problem is not that the IF fails but it never fails even when it should fail

Comment: `UPDATE()` essentially tells you *whether the column was mentioned in the `SET` clause*, **not** whether it actually caused a change to occur.

Comment: but the column Volume was't mentioned nowhere

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this in your trigger
The sample will need changes by you offcourse, I dont know your table layout and what exact you want to achieve.

```
update table2
set    TotalValue = Volume * 100
where  ID in (select i.ID from inserted i 
              left outer join deleted d on i.ID = d.ID
              where i.Volume <> isnull(d.Volume, -1)
             )
```

Also note that when you are inserting the deleted table will be empty.

Comment: the problem is not in the trigger but in entity framework (I believe). the problem is that the IF never fails even when it should fail

Comment: you can test that by modifying records in SSMS (so not by EF) and see what happens

Comment: but again, the result will be different when you update just one, or more than one record in one statement

Comment: I now this but I update only one record at time. I have made test with SSMS and the trigger work rightly

Comment: @christiancut - you should be modelling your database *separately* from any particular application that interacts with it. Just because *your current application* doesn't perform any multi-row inserts or updates *doesn't* mean that you shouldn't consider that it may in the future or that ad-hoc SQL updates might not need to be applied. As such, deploying a trigger that is broken for multi-row DML is deploying a bug.

Comment: What I am trying to show in my answer is a way to check if the value in the column 'volume' has changed or not and how to use that in your update statement. I believe that was your question, was it not ? It might not do yet what you want but that can be easily altered by you

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm not asking for tips on how to develop a trigger. I know how to develop a trigger and the trigger works correctly even with multi-line update. The title of the post expressly asks why, if a column is updated by entity framework, the trigger fails to understand which column has been updated

Comment: @GuidoG No, It was not my question. My question is why, if a column is updated by entity framework, the trigger fails to understand which column has been updated. If I update the record via SSMS, the trigger is OK

Comment: I dont use EF because of this kind of problems. But anyway, in my answer you can find an alternative way to check if the column 'volume' has changed or not. Maybe rewriting your trigger like that can overcome the problem you have with updating from EF ?